# Objects eligible for GC in heap dump?

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I have got the heap dump at point of time . is there a way i can see how many/which probable objects( or how much probable memory) will be reclaimed(free) once another GC(minor/major)
GC is run ?

I have access to Memory Analyzer tool(MAT),jvisualVM,Jprofiler tools and can use any one of them

[image]

Comment: In the System (and Runtime) class(es) there are methods to querry the current free memory for the current JVM. I dont know the exact method names, but a quick lookaround will do. (It is wel documented)

Comment: Usually heap dump do not contains such objects because creating heap dump is invoking GC (if you do not ask specificaly not to). Which tool do you use btw?

Comment: @talex please see mine update in post

Comment: here the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20405267/3656904

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these references go to the doc pages on that):

- [Eclipse Memory Analyzer Tool](https://wiki.eclipse.org/MemoryAnalyzer/FAQ#How_to_analyse_unreachable_objects)
- [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/reachability.jsp)

***Update.*** Just noticed you have MAT so try the first thing
***Update 2.*** Example

Also could you please share more context on what are you trying to accomplish with this?
(r[image: unreachable_objects tab]

Comment: on overview tab it displays  `Size 143 MB Classes 12K Objects 2m Classloader 120` but when i clean  unreachable object histogram its displays `shallow heap size as 864,367,304(864MB)` which one is correct ?

Comment: @user3198603 can you please post all of that with screenshots? like when you just load it, which action do you trigger and what you see afterwards

Comment: @Ival please see screen shot attached. On details page  it displays total size as 157.3MB but when i click on unreachable object it displays total size as 864 MB. Does it mean 864MB size are for unreachable object and 157MB size are for reachable object ?

Comment: i am trying to see what is the size of dead/unreachable objects that can be cleared by next GC

Comment: @user3198603 I went ahead and attached an example. In my case it's ~13Mb of unreachable objects (and 40Mb of reachable ones in the Overview tab in my case)

Comment: so after next GC most probably you'll 143Mb of alive data (or maybe more) and 864Mb will go away (although that depends on GC algorithm alot, some are latency based so they'll clean up as much as they can in the time they have allocated)

Comment: an object being unreachable does not guarantee that the next GC will free the memory. Generational and region-based collectors don't collect everything unless necessary.

Comment: @Ivan how come 143 MB data of live data and 864 MB data will go away after next GC? As you have just 13MB of unreachable object at this point of time this data is the only probable candidate to go away . Right ?

Comment: @the8472 I agree  `an object being unreachable does not guarantee that the next GC will free the memory. ` That depends whether minor or major GC getting triggered as minor will collect only unreachable objects from young generation not from old generation.

Comment: @user3198603 1) 143Mb of live data won't go away in your case 2) In my case yes, 13Mb is what can go away during next GC

Comment: Yes i mentioned it for your case only