# Java heap dump file (.hprof) is much larger than heap size in eclipse MAT

Tags: java, garbage-collection, eclipse-mat

I have some frequent full GC problems in production with Java, I suspect the memory was allocated by network library for buffering TCP request result.

I have dump the Java heap when the memory usage is high (about 8GB). I tried to analyze the .HPROF file with eclipse MAT, the file is about 8GB.

But in eclipse MAT, the total heap size is about 200 MB, so I could not find which objects are taking up to 8GB heap memory.

Since eclipse MAT is not showing the full heap dump content, I don't know how to find why the application is taking so much memory.

Comment: Do you have GC logs?

Comment: Not all of the process memory is allocated to the heap

Comment: I suspect Netty is allocating off-heap memory,  I have found huge blank byte[] arrays in memory dump

Comment: There is error in thrift decoding, thrift client is creating a near 2g byte array for buffering

Comment: Did you try other heap dump analyzing tools?

Comment: I have tried jxray, jxray can find huge blank byte[] in memory dump

Comment: I think the question is resolved. Now I need to stop thrift protocol parser to create huge blank buffer, this is another topic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [eclipse memory analyzer sees small part (363,2MB) of entire heap dump (8GB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085538/eclipse-memory-analyzer-sees-small-part-363-2mb-of-entire-heap-dump-8gb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MAT memory analyzer to open the hprof dump, it may be that the rest of the heap are unreachable objects, which MAT hides by default, see
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20405267/3484881